# unable to use pyodbc on mac

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, pypyodbc, ipython-sql

i am trying to use pyodbc to connect to azure sql from python and i am getting this error saying pyodbc module not found although i have it installed as you can see in snippet below:

```
(apienv) (base) manishshukla@Manishs-MacBook-Pro scriptureApi % pip3 install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.32-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (68 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.32
(apienv) (base) manishshukla@Manishs-MacBook-Pro scriptureApi % python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
>>>
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show the output of `pip3 -V`, `python3 -V`, and `which python3`. I guess you installed pyodbc on Python 3.9 (`cp39`), which is a different version of Python than `python3` (Python 3.8.5).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)